# xml to xml with xslt keep heading

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm novice on xml convert xml useing xslt, in here, I found many answer to help me process xml  convert, but I still have problem and can not find the solution, so need help.
how to keep heading when use xslt process?

input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="BIG5"?>
<!DOCTYPE ROWSET SYSTEM "99_recatalog_big5.dtd"[
<!ENTITY  % basetag  SYSTEM "99_basic_a_big5.ent" >
<!ENTITY  % filetag  SYSTEM "99_records_big5.ent" >]>
<ROWSET>
</ROWSET>
```

output xml heading same as input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="BIG5"?>
<!DOCTYPE ROWSET SYSTEM "99_recatalog_big5.dtd"[
<!ENTITY  % basetag  SYSTEM "99_basic_a_big5.ent" >
<!ENTITY  % filetag  SYSTEM "99_records_big5.ent" >]>
<ROWSET>
</ROWSET>
```

second output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ROWSET SYSTEM "94_recatalog_big5.dtd"[
<!ENTITY  % basetag  SYSTEM "94_basic_a_big5.ent" >
<!ENTITY  % switchtag  SYSTEM "94_records_big5.ent" >]>
<ROWSET>
</ROWSET>
```

has any way can do that in xslt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in straight XSLT.

Andrew Welch has produced a tool called Lexev (bundled with KernowforSaxon, I believe) which tackles this problem by preprocessing the DTD into an XML representation, and then post-processing the result to turn it back into a DTD.

Comment: @CanChang If this answer was helpful to you, you should _accept_ it by clicking the tick on the left so that it appears in green.